# How to grab .aspx Page Name from the URL?

Tags: asp.net

What object can I use to get the current PageName.aspx (including the extension .aspx) from the URL?  I can't find what object and method to allow me to grab this when I'm on a page.

Comment: You could google this you know.  Type in get page name in asp.net inside of google and it works wonders.

Comment: If "googling" bought up stack overflow page then you should've posted that question/answer. If it did not then it should be asked here like this so that StackOverflow is the first port of call for anything that is "googled".

Comment: @LymanZerga and @Robin Day, the first answer on Google (and perhaps additional answers), which is www.aspcode.net/Get-current-page-name.aspx on my search, leads to a `FileInfo` based solution. See my answer below about the drawbacks of it. This is why such question, which seems so trivial, **still deserves a decent discussion**, sharing the knowledge and experience of all of us. Cheers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pino here's the source lil man: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42433

```
  string sPagePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    System.IO.FileInfo oFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPagePath);
    string sPageName = oFileInfo.Name;
```

Answer (score 16):

Note that sometimes, on shared hosting like GoDaddy, you might not have the permission to create a new `FileInfo` object. Yes, believe it.

So I suggest you use this snippet:

```
string fullPath = /* System.Web.HttpContext.Current. (optional in most cases) */ Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
```

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Very nice indeed, especially wrapped up in a single statement:  `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)`

Comment: Presumably `GetFileName` and `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` are simply parsing the name passed in and not actually doing anything with the filesystem...

Answer (score 4):

http://www.aspcode.net/Get-current-page-name.aspx

```
public string GetCurrentPageName() 
{ 
    string sPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; 
    System.IO.FileInfo oInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPath); 
    string sRet = oInfo.Name; 
    return sRet; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

Split about '/', last item is your file name.

Answer (score 1):

Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath) can be used to fetch the actual file name

Answer (score 1):

I used: `Request.Url.LocalPath`, which gave me "/default.aspx", even when full URL would be https://www.example.com/?foo=bar. You just need to strip the leading `/`.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
    var pageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.ToString());
    Response.Write(pageName);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string pageName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);
```