# Filter string in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I am new to the asp.net c# development i need to get "test.aspx" part only from this string "/test1/Pages/Request/test.aspx?id=-1" .Please help me if some one know better way to do that ,i check some regular expression methods but still i haven't correct solution.

Thanks

Comment: do you need it IN the `test.aspx` page by chance? in other words, do you want the name of the current requested page?

Comment: yes ,i need to get current request page name,i create base page and inherit other pages from base page and get request URL actual requirement is i want to display request page name only .

Comment: the just get the current page name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1833313/72746

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Uri.AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So can do

```
Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "/test1/Pages/Request/test.aspx?id=-1";
string page = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('/')+1, str.IndexOf('?')-str.LastIndexOf('/')-1);
```

Comment: Do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z.]+)(?=\?)
```

You can use this.Just grab the first group.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pages will all be `.aspx`:
**(?<=/)\w+.aspx(?=\?)**

In C# use:
`@"(?<=/)\w+.aspx(?=\?)"`

---Edit---
If you want to catch more characters, you can modify the bold part of the expression below:
(?<=/)**[\w\.]**+.aspx(?=\?)

The second regex will also match dots in the part preceding `.aspx`.